# How to find out, which hardware component causes a power failure on a Windows 7 machine (Kernel Power error 41(63))?

Tags: windows-7

Since February 2016 my notebook occasionally (up to several times a day) stops working (all of a sudden the screen turns white or black), or reboots itself.

According to `eventvwr`, there are [unexpected power interruptions](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2028504), which cause this.

How can I systematically (no guesses) find out,

1. whether the error is caused by software or hardware (according to the article above, this error may be caused by software problem), and
2. if it's a hardware problem, which component is causing it (which component I have to replace to fix the error)

?

My first guess was the AC-DC adapter, which had an old cable. I replaced it by a new one, but the error persists.

Comment: Review the crash dump (if any)

Comment: Where can I find it?

Comment: Go to Google. Type in `windows crash dump file location`

Comment: You will have to `guess systematically` like a detective - in complex systems there is no one sheet troubleshooting guide.

Comment: @VojtěchDohnal OK. Which components are the obvious suspects?

Comment: It would be difficult to guess with no info, but this seems to be rather a hardware problem, or perhaps graphics card issue (some driver problem) - if the screen turns white. But this is rather for specialized repair service. You may try to update drivers and BIOS, if there is some software bug. Also check temperature of your system.